# Kotlin: Can I assign a function to a variable in a companion object from main?

Tags: kotlin

New to kotlin, wondering if it's possible to dynamically assign
a function to a companion object's variable. Read the docs and some answers here but there's no mentioning about this.

```
class Printer {
    companion object {
        fun printAnything() {
            println("printing anything..")
        }
    }
}

fun printA() {
    println("printing A!")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    printA()
    Printer.printAnything = :: printA // doesn't compile, perhaps a different way?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reassign a function that was declared with `fun`. It will always point to the same function. But you can make a `var` that holds a reference to a function. A `var` or `val` property holding a function can be invoked as a function, the same as if it was a `fun` declaration.

```kotlin
fun defaultPrintAnything() {
    println("printing anything...")
}

var printAnything = ::defaultPrintAnything

fun printA() {
    println("printing A!")
}

fun main() {
    printAnything() // calls defaultPrintAnything
    printAnything = ::printA
    printAnything() // calls printA
}
```

You can make a variable like this anywhere you like, whether it's in a companion object or not. So yes, you can make your `Printer` companion object this way:

```kotlin
class Printer {
    companion object {
        var printAnything = {
            println("printing anything..")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your fast and on point answer , thank you!

Comment: companion object {
        const val URL =
            "https://flictrick.com/flictrick_content/content/Comedy/Anjum Ki Siyaahi Slam Poetry Faizan Anjum/Video/Anjum Ki Siyaahi.mp4"
          //  "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    }    How can i pass the dyamic variable at the place of link